# How do I get the month and day in excel cell using VBA?

Tags: vba, date, excel

So here's my scenario:

I have a Cisco login and logout report that exports my data into Excel. Great! The only problem is that it gives me multiple login times in a single day, so I'm trying to get just the first login attempt and throw the rest away in that one day and move to the next.

The cell is pre-formatted by Cisco as `m/d/yyyy" "h\:mm\:ss AM/PM`. I'm teaching myself VBA and I want to get just the m/d/yyyy from that single cell, and compare it to other cells. If the date exists, I want to delete those rows.

Example:

```
5/2/2012 2:55:12PM
5/2/2012 3:00:00PM
5/2/2012 3:01:00PM
5/3/2012 2:56:01PM
```

I want to delete the second and third entries in a for loop.

Let me know if this is not clear, and thank yo so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that `preformatted by Cisco as m/d/yyyy" "h\:mm\:ss AM/PM.` The sample above however doesn't match that format. The sample that you gave should have been

```
5/2/2012 2:55:12 PM
5/2/2012 3:00:00 PM
5/2/2012 3:01:00 PM
5/3/2012 2:56:01 PM
```

i.e with a space before `PM`

This code sample below is based on the format `m/d/yyyy h\:mm\:ss AM/PM`

**CODE**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim delRange As Range

    '~~> Set this to the sheet where you have the data
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Sort the data in ascending order
        .Range("A:A").Sort key1:=.Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending

        '~~> Get the last row
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> loop through the cells
        For i = 2 To lRow
            '~~> Check if date matches
            If Application.Evaluate("=DATE(YEAR(A" & i & "),MONTH(A" & i & "),DAY(A" & i & "))") = _
            Application.Evaluate("=DATE(YEAR(A" & i - 1 & "),MONTH(A" & i - 1 & "),DAY(A" & i - 1 & "))") Then
                '~~> Check if the value is greater
                If .Range("A" & i).Value > .Range("A" & i - 1).Value Then
                    '~~> identify cells to delete
                    If delRange Is Nothing Then
                        Set delRange = .Range("A" & i)
                    Else
                        Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Range("A" & i))
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        '~~> Delete cells
        If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: I see...I will try this. In regards to your comment that the formatting doesn't match, I'm just copying the format as it was entered in Excel and copied a couple of cells to show as an example. I will let you know what I get, thank you very much!

Comment: No worries. Lemme know. if there is no space before `PM` then we will have to slightly alter the code.

Comment: @ siddharth WOW! This did it! Thank you so much! I'm curious, could you point me in the right direction to better understand that =Date stuff you had in the evaluate function?  I'm going to have to read through this a couple of times to figure it out and better understand! +1 for you!

Comment: `Excel Help` is self sufficient when it comes to explaining it's native functions :) Free `F1` to launch the help. Let me know if you still have any problems.